# Adding two overlays in FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, overlay

I am adding an animated PNG overlay to an existing video with some text written right below the gif in ffmpeg using the command:

```
 .\ffmpeg.exe -i vid.mp4 -ignore_loop 0 -i elephant.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=(main_w-overlay_w-10):y=(main_h-overlay_h-30):shortest=1, drawtext=fontfile=seguiemj.ttf:text='This is a test': fontcolor=white: fontsize=48: x=(w-text_w-250): y=(h-text_h-10)" output.mp4
```

Now, instead of text, I want to add another png in the same position as the text and using the same relative equations but I'm not sure how to write the variables for the second overlay? Since I'm already using `overlay_w` and `overlay_h` for the first image overlay, how can I define other variables for other overlay images?

Comment: So you want the 2nd image to be 250 px from the right edge and 10 px from the bottom?

Comment: @Gyan In a way, yes. But I'm also interested in how I can set the location relative to the other image as well. I want to set the poistion of the first image,  then the other one exactly below it